# PgPool, change max password size

Tags: c, postgresql, pgpool

I am using pgpool with postgres and to authenticate users I am using PAM with JWT tokens,
however I just discovered that pgpool does not accept passwords longer than a certain value and it seems that this value is hardcoded: (`pool.auth.c`)

```c
if (*pwdSize > MAX_PASSWORD_SIZE)
    {
        ereport(ERROR,
                (errmsg("authentication failed"),
                 errdetail("invalid authentication packet. password is too long. password length is %d", *pwdSize)));

        /*
         * We do not read to throw away packet here. Since it is possible that
         * it's a denial of service attack.
         */
    }
```

and in `pool.h`

```c
#define MAX_PASSWORD_SIZE       1024
```

so, if I try to connect to pgpool like this:

```bash
export PGPASSWORD=longStringToken...


psql "sslmode=verify-ca sslrootcert=root.crt host=localhost user=mypamuser port=5432 dbname=postgres"
```

I will receive the following error:

```
authentication failed
DETAIL:  invalid authentication packet. password is too long. password length is 1056
```

If I try the same connecting directly to postgres I have no issue.

Is there a way to change the value of `MAX_PASSWORD_SIZE` **without changing the source code** or somehow skip that check?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You have found the spot in the source code.  Change it.

Comment: @jjanes Maybe I did not express myself correctly. I would like to change that value through configuration. I do not want to change the source code.

Comment: Based on the code snippet you have shown, it is compiled in and so not configurable without recompilation.